# Getting the data from a SOAP Feed

Tags: php, xml, database, soap, nusoap

I'm going to start this off saying I understand nothing of this. I've been looking at code for days and I can't wrap my head around SOAP Feeds. I've looked up documentation and videos and other stack overflow questions but without a basic understanding, I'm just not picking up anything.

I have a document from a company I'm trying to grab their feed from, I'm looking to put this information into a database. They've given me some sample data and php code to start me off, but I can't get it to work.

```
<?php
require_once('../lib/nusoap.php'); // includes nusoap class
// Create object
$client = new nusoap_client('https://services.ironsolutions.com/SearchDataService/SearchDataService.asmx?wsdl', true); 
$client->setHeaders("<AuthHeader><Email>webservice@ironsolutions.com</UserName><Password>IRON123</Password></AuthHeader>"); 
// Call method -- for all equip use null instead of Array(...)
$result = $client->call('GetInventoryList', Array('type' => "TR", 'make' => "CIH"));

if ($client->fault) { // fault if any
   echo 'Fault'; print_r($result);
} else {
   // Check for errors
   $err = $client->getError();

   if ($err) { // Display the error
   echo 'Error' . $err ; }
   else { // Display the result echo 'Result';
   print_r($result); }
}
?>
```

Now I did notice that in the AuthHeader it has a Email opening and a UserName closing, I'm not sure which one it's actually supposed to be. My screen shows blank no matter what I do, so it's hard to troubleshoot.

Is this the way to grab the info? Is there an easier method? What is going on here that returns just a blank page? Any info would help.

Comment: If you fling the URL to the WSDL file in a browser (`https://services.ironsolutions.com/SearchDataService/SearchDataService.asmx?wsdl`), you can see the message definition.  The `<AuthHeader>` element wants an `<Email>` element (not `<UserName>`.  Have you validated that you can actually call the service outside of PHP? I'd do that first - get a hold of either SoapUI, or the PostMan plugin for Chrome and see if you can make a call to the service on that URL.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to SOAP, the best way to figure out web services is to use a known-good client implementation to access the web service.  This way you know if something goes wrong that the problem is likely on the server side.

SOAP UI is good for this sort of thing.  Using SOAP UI, the following payload was created from the WSDL in your example:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://services.ironsolutions.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <ser:AuthHeader>
         <ser:Password>IRON123</ser:Password>
         <ser:Email>webservice@ironsolutions.com</ser:Email>
      </ser:AuthHeader>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:GetInventoryList>
         <ser:p_type>TR</ser:p_type>
         <ser:p_make>CIH</ser:p_make>
      </ser:GetInventoryList>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This shows 2 problems with your example:

1. The header is indeed malformed.  `Email` is the correct tag to use.
2. Your request fields in your sample code are `type` and `make` but should be `p_type` and `p_make` according to the WSDL.

If I had to guess, the resulting blank screen is due to the server side eating the exception when it can't deserialize the SOAP message due to the XML error in the header.  If you look at the HTTP response, it might be a 500 error indicating the server puked but has error pages/stack traces turned off.

Give it a try with SOAP UI, get it working, then recreate the SOAP UI message in your PHP code.  If you want to debug how your PHP client is forming the SOAP message, SOAP UI will allow you to mock the service so that you can intercept and view the PHP generated SOAP message.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to use SoapUI, I downloaded it but I don't know where to submit the wsdl or credentials. I've fixed the code, I now get a: Fault: Array ( [faultcode] => soap:Client [faultstring] => Unauthorized [detail] => )

Is this the correct way to submit credentials?

    $client->setHeaders("<AuthHeader><Email>webservice@ironsolutions.com</Email><Password>IRON123</Password></AuthHeader>");

Comment: That is the result I got, so it is probably working.  You just need the correct credentials.  I'd suggest reading up about how to use SoapUI; it will help you be more efficient when interfacing with web services.

Comment: Yeah, I did some youtube tutorials and got it to work later on. Thanks a lot. One more question before I go out on my own again, with the Unauthorized, would that just be because the username and password is potentially wrong, or is there another variable I need to make sure is set on my account to read the information? And if so what would it be called?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is their server telling you that the username/password is wrong.  You'd probably have to ask the people hosting the web service what they expect for username/password.  There should not be anything additional beyond what you've done to make it work if you have the correct username/password.